# Saving CheckboxGroup values XPages

Tags: xpages

I am working on my first Notes/XPages/Java application and I am stuck at some of the basic 'crud' level. The following is part of the managed bean. I can load the data on to the XPage, but saving the Checkbox field is causing me problems, i.e. it won't save. I assume it is to do with the data type as the CheckboxGroup is multivalued.

Form Fields are:
Category
Employment Role

Variables

```
public class TrainingModule implements Serializable {
private String Category;
private Object EmploymentRole;

public String getCategory() {
return Category; }

public void setCategory(final String category) {
Category = category;}

public Object getEmploymentRole() {
return EmploymentRole;}

public void setEmploymentRole(final Object employmentRole) {
EmploymentRole = employmentRole;}
```

Load Method

```
public void load(final String unid) {
    setUnid(unid);
    Document doc = null;
    try {
        doc = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase().getDocumentByUNID(getUnid());
        setCategory(doc.getItemValueString("Category"));
        setEmploymentRole(doc.getItemValue("EmploymentRole"));
etc
```

Save Method

```
public boolean saveData() {
    boolean result = false;
    Document doc = null;

    try {

        doc.replaceItemValue("Category", Category);
        doc.replaceItemValue("EmploymentRole", EmploymentRole);

        result = doc.save()

etc
```

XPage

```
<xp:checkBoxGroup id="checkBoxGroup1" 
value="#{TrainingModule.employmentRole}">
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Admin" itemValue="Admin">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Installation" itemValue="Installation">
</xp:selectItem>
<xp:selectItem itemLabel="Proj Man" itemValue="Proj Man">
</xp:selectItem>
</xp:checkBoxGroup>
```

I know there are similar postings, but I just can't seem to relate them to what I am trying to achieve.

My next task will be using upload and download controls with Java so any hints or traps to avoid would be great. 
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I assume you intentionally left out the line in your save method that sets the doc object? If not then you should instantiate your doc object, too, as it now is set to null so the code will not be executed and instead it falls into the catch block.

Comment: @OliverBusse Yes sorry Oliver, I was trying not to put too much code - a mistake.
    doc = ExtLibUtil.getCurrentDatabase().getDocumentByUNID(
      getUnid());

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define your employment roles as a field of type `ArrayList<String>`:

```java
private List<String> employmentRoles = new ArrayList<String>();

public void setEmploymentRoles(List<String> employmentRoles) {
    this.employmentRoles = employmentRoles;
}

public List<String> getEmploymentRoles() {
    return employmentRoles;
}
```

Read the values with

```java
setEmploymentRoles(doc.getItemValue("EmploymentRole"));
```

and save the values with

```java
doc.replaceItemValue("EmploymentRole", new Vector(getEmploymentRoles()));
```

Btw, you shouldn't start a field name with a capital letter. Look here for [Java naming conventions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_%28programming%29#Java).

Comment: Brilliant Knut it works, thank you so much for the help guys. Thanks for the tip on Field Names, I am moving over old applications to Java/Xpages, before I knew better they were all done with a capital letter.

Comment: may I ask how you reset them, or fill them with initial value(s)?

Comment: @user1699830 you'd define an ArrayList list, add the values and call setEmploymentRoles() with your created list: `List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>(); list.add("firstValue"); list.add("secondValue"); setEmploymentRoles(list);`

Answer (score 0):

Since you need to load/save your data, you might be better off with an object data source. Anyway try this:

```
public Object[] getEmploymentRole() {
return EmploymentRole;}

public void setEmploymentRole(final Object[] employmentRole) {
EmploymentRole = employmentRole;}
```

An array can't be cast to an Object and a checkboxgroup tries to get/set an array.

This then leads to a slight change in your save method:

```
    doc.replaceItemValue("Category", Category);
    Vector v = new Vector(Arrays.asList(EmploymentRole));
    doc.replaceItemValue("EmploymentRole", v);
```

Let us know how it goes

Comment: Hi, I get a warning with the Vector - Vector is a raw type. References to generic type Vector<E> should be parameterized. But more importantly this breaks my load - The method setEmploymentRole(Object[]) in the type TrainingModule is not applicable for the arguments (Vector)

Comment: Mark, of course it brakes your load. Thought based on the changed save method you figured out that load needs to be adjusted too. The Notes Java api uses raw Vectors, so ignore the warning or use the recommendation with the annotation

Comment: Hi yes sorry, I am new to Java, so it is baby steps for me a the moment, I did try to figure it out, but couldn't get there. Many thanks.

Comment: In your load you need this.EmploymentRole = doc.getItemValue("EmploymentRole").toArray();  you also want to use lowercase to start a variable. It is custom to use Uppercase for class names only. camelCase is common, underscore less so

Comment: Excellent, all these snippets help me up the learning curve. I will sort my cases out. I am about to attempt the same as above, but with a FileUpload and Download control, I imagine it will not be that straight forward, are you aware of any tips or pointers before I start.